# Interpolation with CUDA Texture memory

Tags: cuda, textures, gpu, cuda.net

I would like to use the Texture Memory for Interpolation of Data. I have 2 Arrays (namely A[i] and B[i]) and I would want to interpolate Data between them. I thought I could bind them to Texture Memory and set the interpolation but I am not sure how I can do that.

The examples that come with CUDA use the A[i-1] and A[i+1] for the interpolation.

Is there any way to do what I planned? I'm trying this because I think I can get a good speedup.

Comment: There is an extensive discussion at [Writing CUDA kernels for interpolation](https://vitalitylearning2021.github.io/interpolationCUDA/) on how implementing interpolation using CUDA texture memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with texture memory, and it is fast.  I personally use [ArrayFire](http://accelereyes.com/arrayfire) to accomplish these kinds of operations, because it is faster than I can hope to code by hand.

If you want to code by hand yourself in CUDA, something like this is what you want:

```
// outside kernel

texture<float,1>  A;
cudaChannelFormatDesc desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<float>();
cudaArray *arr = NULL;
cudaError_t e = cudaMallocArray(&arr, &desc, 1, length);
A.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;
A.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeClamp;
cudaBindTextureToArray(A, arr, desc);

...

// inside kernel
    
valA = tex1D(A,1,idx)
valB = tex1D(B,1,idx)

float f = 0.5;
output  = (f)*valA + (1-f)*valB;
```

If you want to just plug-in ArrayFire (which in my experience is faster than what I try to code by hand, not to mention way simpler to use), then you'll want:

```
// in arrayfire
array A = randu(10,1);
array B = randu(10,1);
float f = 0.5;
array C = (f)*A + (1-f)*B;
```

The above assumes you want to interpolate between corresponding indices of 2 different arrays or matrices.  There are [other interpolation functions](http://www.accelereyes.com/arrayfire/c/group__interpolation.htm) available too.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not used to developing with CUDA, using texture memory is not the easiest thing to start with.

I'd suggest you to try writing **a first parallel version** of your algorithm in CUDA with no optimisation. Then, **use the NVIDIA Visual Profiler** on your application to figure out whether you need to set up texture memory to optimize your memory accesses.

Remember that **the earlier you optimize, the trickier it is to debug**.

Last but not least, the latest CUDA version (CUDA 5, still in release candidate) is able to **automatically store your data in texture memory** as long as you declare the input buffers passed as parameters to your kernel as `const restrict` pointers.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I already have a first parallel version. But the speedup compared to a CPU is not very impressive. That's why i would want to try this out.

Comment: Run the profiler first. Your problem might be anything but memory accesses.

Comment: It's not that i have a problem. I would just want to compare the result, so it would be helpful if I know how to do that.